# Losing a right-joined row when doing a NOT IN

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables:

```
email_addr_bean_rel

    bean_id  |  email_address_id

email_addresses

    id       |  email_address

prospect_lists_prospects

    id       |  related_id
```

The above is a huge simplification to demonstrate the issue.  What I need is a list of all related_ids and all available email addresses.  But I have to start the query on the email_addresses table.  So I'm using a RIGHT JOIN to get any related_ids that don't have email addresses.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
       plp.related_id,
       ea.email_address
FROM   email_addresses AS ea 
       JOIN email_addr_bean_rel AS eabr 
         ON ea.id = eabr.email_address_id 
       RIGHT JOIN prospect_lists_prospects AS plp 
         ON eabr.bean_id = plp.related_id 
WHERE
      ea.email_address NOT IN ("x", "y", "z")
```

If I take out the WHERE clause, I get all related ids and the email_address is set to NULL for the ones that don't match up (as expected).  But when I add in the WHERE clause, I lose those RIGHT JOINED records.

Is there some aspect of `NOT IN` or `RIGHT JOIN` that I'm missing that would cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ea.email_address` is **NULL**. But `NULL NOT IN ("x", "y", "z")` always evaluates to **NULL**.

I think you need this:

```
WHERE (ea.email_address is NULL) or (ea.email_address NOT IN ("x", "y", "z"))
```

Comment: I used COALESCE to try to account for this, but I guess that doesn't happen until after the WHERE clause is evaluated?

Comment: @Anthony I have no idea where and how have you used COALESCE :)

Comment: Ha, sorry.  I used `COALESCE(ea.email_address, "xxx")` in the SELECT clause so that the value wouldn't be NULL. But it would still be NULL during the WHERE clause.

Comment: For that purpose you should use HAVING clause, not WHERE. Note: don't forget to add an alias for this column in SELECT clause and then use it in HAVING.

Comment: By the way, the real order of SQL clauses is this: FROM->WHERE->SELECT->GROUP BY->HAVING->ORDER BY->LIMIT. That's why you cannot use anything in WHERE clause from SELECT clause.

Comment: The problem was that I had already written a 5 part query and I realized that the way I wrote it I was not getting the related ids that didn't have an email address. So I thought "Oh, I'll just make it a right join." But then I ran into the above issue. So rewriting the entire query to use HAVING or to start on the table with the related ids was going to be more time than I was allotted.  Your fix was perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I was able to just replace WHERE with HAVING for the whole thing and it still kicks back the same results, but faster.  A bit nervous since I don't have time to do more testing, but I think you've helped beyond this question.